# docker image ls is not showing the installed base images ("FROM" images)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following `Dockerfile` and as you can see I'm using `python:3.10.4` as a base image

```
FROM python:3.10.4

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "bmi.py"]
```

After I build the image using `docker build` the image built successfully and I can see it when I list the images.

however the base image which is `python` with the tag `3.10.4` is not showing

[image]

note that when I build another image of my Dockerfile, I can see from the output that the base image `python:3.10.4` is loaded from the cache.

[image]

And that means the base image `python:3.10.4` is installed and cached successfully but why it is not showing when I list the images, even when I use the `-a` flag, like the following

```
docker image ls -a
```

my docker version is `Docker version 20.10.13, build a224086`

my OS is `windows 10`

Comment: Note that using `FROM python` is probably going to cause your problems some day, because you don't know which version of Python you're getting. Consider replacing that with `FROM python:3.10` (or whatever version is appropriate).

Comment: @larsks thanks for the note, I rewrite the FROM statement to use `python:3.10.4` then I built an image, but still the base image is not showing when I list the images. I had updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using Docker [buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/).

While the traditional `docker build` mechanism would pull referenced images into the local image collection, buildkit has its own caching mechanism and the images it pulls won't show up in the output of `docker image ls`.

Comment: yup turning off buildkit `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build .` make the base image showable when running `docker image ls`